# Does php code not run?No error message

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, pdo

I try this php code(I have already read about sql Injection)but apparently it does not run, no error message or anything else ...

```
<?php
function SignIn(){
  session_start();
  require_once("dbConnection.php");
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
       $db_handle = new DBConnection();
     $username = $_POST["username"];
     if(filter_var($username, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)===true && strpos(explode('@',$username),"studio.unibo.it")===true){
         $query =  $db_con->prepare("SELECT * FROM studenti_in_sessione
         WHERE Username=:username");
         $query->execute(array(":username"=>$username));
         $row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
         $count = $query->rowCount();
         if($row['Username']==$username){
            echo "<script language = javascript>
                alert(\"Autenticazione riuscita,Le invieremo nella mail istituzionale un codice univoco di autenticazione.\");
                window.history.go(-1);
            </script>";
            $querySession = $db_con->prepare("SELECT Nome, Cognome, Matricola FROM studenti_in_sessione
       WHERE Username:=username");
       $querySession->execute(array(":username"=>$username));
       $rowStud = $querySession->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
       $exit = array_values($rowStud);
       $queryInsert = $db_con->prepare("INSERT INTO studente (Nome, Cognome, Matricola, Username, Codice) VALUES('".$exit[0]."',
          '".$exit[1]."','".$exit[2]."','".$username."');");
       $resultInsert = $queryInsert->execute();
       sendCode($username);
     }
      }}else{
          echo "<script language = javascript>
                alert(\"L'indirizzo deve essere @studio.unibo.it.\");
                window.history.go(-1);
                </script>";
  }
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        SignIn();
  }

?>
```

This is html form

```
<div class="box-header">
                <h2>Login</h2>
            </div>
            <form name="form" class="form"  method="POST">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <br/>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
            <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Login">
        </div>
```

Finally script.js

```
$('document').ready(function()
{ 
     /* validation */
  $(".form").validate({
      rules:
   {
   user_email: {
            required: true,
            email: true
            },
    },
       messages:
    {
            user_email: "please enter your email address",
       },
    submitHandler: submitForm 
       });  
    /* validation */

    /* login submit */
    function submitForm()
    {  
   var data = $(".form").serialize();

   $.ajax({

   type : 'POST',
   url  : '../Slide_upload/database/signIn.php',
   data : data,
   success :  function(response){      
     if(response=="ok"){

     }
     else{

     }
     }
   });
    return false;
  }
    /* login submit */
});
```

I probably made mistakes but I can not figure out where ...

Comment: you need to debug this yourself. add echo on each line and verify

Comment: After `<?php` add `error_reporting(E_ALL);ini_set('display_errors',1);session_start();` in your `signIn.php` and remove `session_start();` inside function.Now submit form and check your browser console for errors or success

Comment: If the code doesn't run at all and the page is blank, the reason is usually a syntax error.

Comment: You are using the return value of `strpos` and checking it's true (using ===), try using `!== false` as `strpos` will return a numerical position if it finds the string and not true.

Comment: Unfortunately none of these solutions works

Answer (score 0):

For sure, you are missing a bracket to close your function that is not being executed.
Add it before the lines

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    SignIn();
```

}

This will make your function call working.